Session Cart Resets After First Product Addition in Express.js Application
I'm building an online store application using Express.js, and I'm having trouble with session persistence. The cart works fine the first time I add a product, but if I add another product or make any subsequent request, the cart becomes undefined again.
Here's my code:
cartController.ts
import productModel from "../models/productModel";

declare module 'express-session' {
    interface SessionData {
        cart?: { id: string, title: string, quantity: number, price: number, image: string }[];
    }
}



 //GET add product to cart
const addToCart = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

    try {
        const id = req.params.id;

        const product = await productModel.findById(id)

        if (typeof req.session.cart === "undefined") {
            req.session.cart = [];
            req.session.cart.push({
                id: product?.id,
                title: product?.title!,
                quantity: 1,
                price: parseFloat(product?.price.toFixed(2)!),
                image: '/images/' + product?.id + '/' + product?.image
            });
        } else {
            var cart = req.session.cart;
            var newItem = true;

            for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                if (cart[i].id == id) {
                    cart[i].quantity++;
                    newItem = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (newItem) {
                cart.push({
                    id: product?.id,
                    title: product?.title!,
                    quantity: 1,
                    price: parseFloat(product?.price.toFixed(2)!),
                    image: '/images/' + product?.id + '/' + product?.image
                });
            }
        }
        req.flash('success', 'Product added!');
        res.redirect('back');
    }
    catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
};

export { addToCart }

app.ts
//Cart setup
app.get('*', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    res.locals.cart = req.session.cart;
    next();
})


Hi, It means the session is not being maintained, and every request creates a new session. Further more, the cookie carrying sessionID may not be getting saved into the client. This can be checked in Chrome at the option Developer Tools / Application/Cookies. There should be cookie stored here just after adding the first item. This may be the first point of check. Secondly, if it is a cross-site request sharing case, then the request to add item in the client should have been invoked with credentials : 'include'. Please see if is also set.
